# JSP jstl core library - Can not find the tag library descriptor

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am using Eclipse with Web Tool Platform installed. I created a new `.jsp` page, and trying to use the JSTL core library. However, I can't seem to use it, even though it is valid. Here is the screenshot: [image]

The uri I placed is: "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core". Can someone please explain why is it giving me that error and how do I deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download [jstl](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api/1.2.1/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar) jar. Then include it in your `/WEB-INF/lib` folder
 
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) for more info.

Comment: Where do I include it?

Comment: I tried adding it to both, /classes, and /lib folders (like mentioned in the link you told be), but it didn't work. Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: Still not working on /lib folders? Does it same when you include javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar?

Comment: Figured it out, thanks for helping :)

Comment: Wanna share your solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem with Java 8, Tomcat 8 and after much searching found that i needed to include [TomCat Tag libs into my tomcat library](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-taglibs.cgi).
I hope this helps.